# How to replace "You may also like" to have "Related products" in cart preview page in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

When Customer clicks "Add to cart" button for any product a preview pop up appears, it has "You may also like" it is automatic and is giving wrong products. I want to replace it with "Related products" which we can manage from dashboard.

The code which need to be changed is in stencil under templates/components/cart/preview.html

I see suggested_products I want to remove it and add related_products. I don't know how to do it, I don't know if there is a variable available for related_products

```
{{#if cart.suggested_products}}
            <section class="suggestiveCart">
                <h3>
                    {{lang 'cart.added_to_cart.you_might_also_like'}}&hellip;
                </h3>

                <ul class="productGrid">
                    {{#each cart.suggested_products}}
                        <li class="product">
                            {{> components/products/card hide_product_quick_view=true theme_settings=../theme_settings}}
                        </li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </section>
        {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Related product data is scoped just to the product page--it isn't available in the cart the way suggested products are. The best solution would be to make an ajax request for the product data using the stencil utils library.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/adding-event-hooks-to-your-theme/stencil-utils-api-reference#stencil-utils_product

```
api.product.getById(ID, 'template', (err, response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Karen. but I tried to call the API mentioned and I used 'products/related' as the template. but the response of the API is very long list of products without images. I just need the related products. do you have any idea?

Comment: Hey @HamadaIbrahim, you can also supply a custom template as the template parameter, that uses {{json product.related_products}} to return the related products as a JSON object. That should make it a bit easier to work with.